# How can I block certain file from opening in an Active Directory environment?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am running in Windows Server 2008 Active Directory environment.  I have been asked to deny opening of files of certain file name and file type. For example, the files Read.docx and Apple.apt should not be opened or saved by any means by the system or the user.

When implementing group policy software restrictions, I added the file types as designated file types properties, and I set the file name as per the path rule with a disallowed execution. So far, executable (.exe) files are blocked. However other type of files such as TXT or DOCX, are not being applied by the group policy. How is it possible to block a certain file that we know it's name and extension from being run or created in our environment?

The purpose of this is to avoid a known malware from executing.